# Changing dynamic text that's encapsulated in asterisks (*) to a link on web-page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, hyperlink

I have a weird situation where I need to change text on a html page which looks like this:

```
*www.google.co.uk/Google*
*www.stackoverflow.com/StackOverflow*
```

to an anchor tag:

```
<a href="www.google.co.uk/">Google</a>
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</a>
```

Using JavaScript/Jquery. The first part being the link, the second the text. I have had a few attempts at this and used a few examples from here(SO) but I'm struggling to fit them to my use case.

At first I was trying something like this:

```
var html=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
html = html.replace(/\*([^*]+)\*/g , '<a href="www.google.co.uk>placeholder</a>"');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML=html;
```

Which I realise is not splitting my text, nor is it actually changing the URL but this was me trying to replace only the text that should be links and not the rest of the page. But this just left the link on my page and nothing else.

Then I tried some JQuery, Which I must preface I don't know much about:

```
$("body").children().each(function () {
var reg = new RegExp(/\*([^*]+)\*/g, 'g');
const test = $(this).html( $(this).html().match(reg) );

// $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/^/g,"$") );

console.log(test);
});
```

The result of this was printing out the link, but I figured I'd get some help!

Thanks in advance

EDIT: *2

The html on the site would look like:

```
<div class="tnc"> By making a booking, You are agreeing to the  *https://digital.nhs.uk/about-nhs-digital/terms-and-conditions^terms and conditions* and will follow the COVID-19 precautions set in the email confirmation </div>
```

The expected result:

```
<div class="tnc"> By making a booking, You are agreeing to the  <a href="https://digital.nhs.uk/about-nhs-digital/terms-and-conditions">terms and conditions</a> and will follow the COVID-19 precautions set in the email confirmation </div>
```

This is only a single example, on the page there is multiple similar to that, some dont have divs and are just paragraphs (some even without classes!). I wish I could send a link but its internal.

The links will always be valid with http(s) to begin with and may sometimes end with a file path

Thanks

EDIT: 3

Using Joels code, I am traversing the body looking for links and it seems to be working on all of them which is great! The only issue I'm having now is when i replace a it is not a hyperlink but just text.. Am I missing something obvious?

```
const regex = /\*(.*[.].*)\^(.*)\*/;

$("body").children().each(function () {
  var preText = this.innerHTML;
  var matches = regex.exec(preText);
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = matches[1];
  a.text = matches[2];

  const newText = matches.input.replace(matches[0], a);

  this.innerHTML = newText;
});
```

Comment: Are they separated? Or are they just in the same div with newlines?

Comment: Hey @JoelHager, They are separated inside either paragraphs or spans. They dont have classes and are just text :-/ thanks

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you're saying. Can you post the HTML with the links that you're looking for, and I can work a way to crawl it and get an array of those objects?

Comment: Thanks for the comment below, updating the OP now!

Comment: You'll have to edit your OP to contain the HTML, as you can't post multi-line stuff in comments. :)

Comment: Yeah - See, this is more difficult to work with. There are multiple delimiters `/` in that example, so it'd only capture root-level domains `https://example.com` instead of `https://example.com/path/to/appropriate/file`

Comment: Oh my god you are right  how silly with the forward slash. That is something I can get changed however so the delimiters can be anything. The same with the astrixa. Originally I had them with ^ instead

Comment: I'd *definitely* use something that doesn't include characters for paths or such. `^ would definitely work`

Comment: hey @JoelHager sorry for the late reply it was very early morning where I am haha, I've used your code this morning and modified it to loop over the body. I am getting good results however the link it replaces it with is only text? Could you just glance over to see if im missing something obvious? thanks! (its in the OP)

Comment: Cab you post the code you're  using now in the OP?

Comment: @JoelHager Yeah its under edit 3, thanks buddy

Comment: So in reality, you're scraping *every* div, finding the asterisks, splitting up the text into a link and path with new domain, and then just inserting it right there? Where are you attempting to put those links after you get them?

Comment: @JoelHager I am just trying to replace the text, so my, I've added another edit of what I'm trying to achieve after this code fires. I have not worked on it today though will try again later :-)

Comment: I've edited my answer to do what you're looking for. :)

Comment: @JoelHager That is perfect! You are the best thanks so much! I really mean it

Comment: Happy to have helped! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - So here is the solution that you need. There is some naming I did to make it slightly more readable. Here is what it does:

1. It searches *every* `<div>` for a match to the regex pattern `/\*(?<domain>.*[.].*)\^(?<text>.*)\*/`

This finds the `*` and then starts capturing under the name 'domain'

2. It searches for the delimiter `^`, stopping the first capture group at that, and starting the next capture group called 'text'
3. It keeps capturing until it hits the next `*`
4. It runs the replace command, and it removes the *entire* regex match (from `*` to `*`), and creates a link `<a href='` and then adds the first capture group. It closes the open `<a>` and then uses the 'text' between the tag, and finally closes it.

I added multiple ones with slightly different names to show that it works. :)

Keep in mind, you can change the `div` search to be anything, but it seems as though every link will be inside a div, so that would probably speed things up slightly.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("div");

elements.forEach( element => {
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/\*(?<domain>.*[.].*)\^(?<text>.*)\*/, `<a href="$<domain>">$<text></a>`);
});
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tnc"> By making a booking, You are agreeing to the  *https://digital.nhs.uk/about-nhs-digital/terms-and-conditions^terms and conditions* and will follow the COVID-19 precautions set in the email confirmation </div> 

<div class="tnc"> By making a booking, You are agreeing to the  *https://google.com/about-nhs-digital/terms-and-conditions^terms and conditions* and will follow the COVID-19 precautions set in the email confirmation </div> 

<div class="tnc"> By making a booking, You are agreeing to the  *https://yetanotherdomain.com/about-nhs-digital/^another string* and will follow the COVID-19 precautions set in the email confirmation </div> 

<div class="tnc"> By making a booking, You are agreeing to the  *https://digital3.nhs.uk/about-nhs-digital/terms-and-conditions^other terms* and will follow the COVID-19 precautions set in the email confirmation </div>
```

Comment: Hey Joel, That is incredible what you have done! This is so near to perfect but the only issue with this is the links are inside paragraphs or spans and so they some of them dont have classes. That's why I was trying to loop over the body but your code is so much better!  *edit - thanks for explaining the code too, I will definatly learn from this!

Comment: They can be *anywhere* for this code to work (the RegEx side) I just didn't know how you were getting the list. Just think of `preLinks` as the array of objects that have whatever you're looking to match/work with. :)

Comment: Keep in mind, there are various ways you can verify if it's a good link, but I left it open-ended for you to use. If you want to check `.com/.net/etc` there is an expression for that. This *assumes* that the links are good, and that text is there. It'd get more complicated to account for more use-cases, so I kept it simple. :)

Comment: The links will always be valid and contain: http(s), a file path. I should probably also add that to the OP. Sorry if I'm difficult to work with lol

Comment: Not at all! It's just important stuff to take into account, or solutions may not work as intended. :)